# How do I display an image using javaFX by selecting a file from file explorer

Tags: java, javafx

1.I have a code that opens a pane and I can open file explorer, but I do not know how to open said image when I select it from file explorer. Also this code is meant to be used in different @Overrride statements but I have only managed to get this far using one statement. Is there a way for me to call some of these events from another Override statement?

```
  @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    //Stage
    primaryStage.setTitle("title");
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);


    Button load = new Button("Load");
    load.setOnAction(loadEventListener);

    ImageView myImageView = new ImageView();

    HBox rootBox = new HBox();
    rootBox.getChildren().addAll(load, myImageView);


    //Toolbar
    HBox toolbarArea = new HBox( 10 );
    toolbarArea.setPadding( new Insets( 10 ) );


    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    //Puts buttons on bottom bar
    toolbarArea.getChildren().addAll( load );
    pane.setBottom( toolbarArea );
}

EventHandler<ActionEvent> loadEventListener
        = t -> {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

            //Set extension filter
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG");
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.PNG");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterPNG);

            //Show open file dialog
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

            try {
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
                Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
                ImageView myImageView = new ImageView();
                myImageView.setImage(image);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaFXPixel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an `ImageView` and have shown it in the scene, simply set its image to the image you load.

For this you need to make the `ImageView` an instance variable:

```
private ImageView myImageView ;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    //Stage
    primaryStage.setTitle("title");
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);


    Button load = new Button("Load");
    load.setOnAction(loadEventListener);

    myImageView = new ImageView();

    HBox rootBox = new HBox();
    rootBox.getChildren().addAll(load, myImageView);

    // presumably you intended this somewhere?
    pane.setCenter(rootBox);


    //Toolbar
    HBox toolbarArea = new HBox( 10 );
    toolbarArea.setPadding( new Insets( 10 ) );


    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    //Puts buttons on bottom bar
    toolbarArea.getChildren().addAll( load );
    pane.setBottom( toolbarArea );
}
```

Note there is no need to load a buffered image and then convert it. So all you need in the event handler is

```
    loadEventListener = t -> {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        //Set extension filter
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.PNG");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterPNG);

        //Show open file dialog
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (file != null) {
            Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
            myImageView.setImage(image);
        }

    };
```

Comment: Thank you, so I changed that and its showing my image, but it shows it at the images native resolution. Is there way I can set the window size to a certain amount and it will scale the image to fit in said window?

Comment: @JoePoti Yes, see documentation. You can either specify a [size for the image when you load it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-double-double-boolean-boolean-), or you can [call `setFitWidth/Height()` on the image view](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#fitHeightProperty) to control the size of the view of the image.